# Can projects using PHP framework operate standalone?

Tags: php, zend-framework, symfony1

I am interested in the PHP framework, especially by symfony and ZendFramework, but I am not sure of one thing: I saw the need to type command lines to create a project with these frameworks. Ok, but once the project is finished, is it possible to move files to another server without installing anything (except for Apache)?

Thank you in advance

Ps: No report, but do StackOverflow uses a framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is absolutely possible to run a symfony or zend framework application without installing the framework on the server. Symfony has a special mechanism to pack everything into one folder. If you use zend framework you basically have to copy the "Zend" folder to your "lib" directory and you are ready to go.

As far as I know, StackOverflow is build on ASP.net and C# running on several windows servers.

Answer (score 0):

Firstof, most of those commands are needed for development only. But also you do not have to have the commands in your global path, it's also possible to execute the scripts directly.

In case of symfony that would be something like

```
./symfony-framework/data/bin/symfony
```

if you installed symfony to symfony-framework.

I believe stackoverflow is based on .NET MVC or plain ASP .NET - http://meta.stackoverflow.com will give you that answer

Answer (score 0):

With Zend Framework, it is possible. The Zend_Tool part, which sets up the basics of your project is just addition. You can, but you don't have to use it at all. You can just write the project from scratch yourself, just stick to the standard project architecture.

Anyway, once the project is ready, it does not need any command line setup, other than mayby setting correct file system permission if your project needs to write some files.

I can't say about symphony, but I **assume** it also can be just copied to the target server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, how about ZF, but project made with Symfony can be easily moved to another server just by copying files. However it will be difficult to maintain your project without commands. Also you have to copy all Symfony's core files to your server, but it will be better to install Symfony there before.

Answer (score 0):

About Symfony:

Usually, you develop locally on your dev environment (using Wampserver or MAMP for example). You will require access to the command line to run symfony commands, specially for complex tasks like ORM tasks. So you have to install symfony on that environment.
According to the [official doc](http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_4/en/03-Symfony-Installation)  the recommended installation method is through SVN (either the trunk or a tag) inside your project folder.

When you'll push the files from your dev environment to another (using project:deploy if you can), all the required files will be pushed.

So there is no need to install (in the sense of "run" or "execute") anything on the live environment server. The only "installation" method that requires an access to the command line is the PEAR install method, which is [not recommended](http://www.symfony-project.org/installation/1_4).
The only problem that I had when I deployed an application was a user permission problem on the cache folder, but that's easy to fix by changing the folder permission.